# import error attempting to import from the directory above

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

Not a python developer and I am clearly missing something fundamental here.  Using Python 3.10.7 and i am getting an error:

```
from ..class_one import ClassOne 
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

when attempting to execute `python run_me.py` script in the example below

I have the following structure with following import statements

```
\Project
    \data_processor
        data_process.py
            from ..class_one import ClassOne  <--getting an error here
    run_me.py
        from data_processor.data_process import DataProcess
    class_one.py
```

interesting that when i type a line `from ..class_one import ClassOne` in `data_process.py` my IDE thinks its completely legit and intellisence works, suggesting that i import `ClassOne`.

Most of the solutions imply Python earlier than v3.3 (changed the way packages are handled), which  isn't the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not allow relative imports beyond the top-level package. This is why you are seeing the ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package error...

Try to use absolute import, like this:

```
from Project.class_one import ClassOne
```

You can also move the class_one module to a package within the current project, you can create a new package and move the class_one module to it. Then, you can use a relative import to import the ClassOne module:

```
\Project
    \data_processor
        data_process.py
            from my_package.class_one import ClassOne
    run_me.py
        from data_processor.data_process import DataProcess
    \my_package
        class_one.py
```

Finally, it's not recommended (complexity, cause confusion and difficulty to read the code) but I think you can try to use a 'sys.path' to add the parent directory to the Python path. I think it will allow you to use a relative import:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')
from class_one import ClassOne
```

Comment: thank you.  your second suggestion of moving `class_one.py` into its own folder under the `project1`, and then importing it as `my_package.class_one` worked.

Comment: curious about one thing: in the original code, writing the line `from ..class_one import ClassOne`, the `..` bit puts you into `\Project1` directory, which in my understanding is NOT "beyond top-level package", since "top-level package" is `Project1`

Answer (score 1):

#### Why you get that error?

Remember relative imports are resolved using `__package__` variable(I'm talking about `..class_one`). Add a simple print statement in your `data_process.py` to see the value of this variable:

```py
print(__package__)
```

You're in `Project` folder and you run `python run_me.py`, so this variable must be: `'data_processor'`. So you can't go beyond "one" level up. (It follows the dots as we see next).

#### When you can go one level up?

In `run_me.py` change your import statement from:

```py
from data_processor.data_process import DataProcess
```

to

```py
from Project.data_processor.data_process import DataProcess
```

Before running your script, we need to tell Python where to find `Project` folder. It doesn't know right now! We are in `Project` directory and there is no `Project` directory in where we are. So just add it to the `sys.path` in `run_me.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, PATH TO PARENT OF Project DIRECTORY)
```

Now run your command -> `python run_me.py`. Every thing works fine.

Did you notice the value of `__package__`? It's now `'Project.data_processor'`. We went one level down, so we can go one level up .( As I said, it follows the dots.)

---

That was the reason. But what you can do now?

1. I think the most simple solution is to just stick with absolute imports. If you know in which directory you are and check the records in `sys.path`(Add to the paths if necessary), you won't get into problems.
2. You can manually hack `__package__` which I do not recommend. To do so, add:

```py
__package__ = "Project.data_processor"
```

at the top in your `data_process.py` file. Then add this to the `run_me.py`

```bash
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, PATH TO PARENT OF Project DIRECTORY)
```

This way you don't need to change your original import statement. That `from data_processor.data_process import DataProcess` just works.

3. For this option, you don't need to hack `__package__` nor adding any path to the `sys.path`. Just change your import statement from:

```py
from data_processor.data_process import DataProcess
```

to

```py
from Project.data_processor.data_process import DataProcess
```

But for executing your command, you should go to the parent directory and run your script like:

```bash
python -m Project.run_me
```